# API working fine on local but not on Google cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have developed a spring boot application using google cloud mysql. When I'm running my api on local. It is working fine.Data gets stored to GCP mysql but when I deploy this to GCP and hit API. It shows internal server error.

Is there's any way to check in GCP why this 500-internal error server occurs?

Comment: And you really have us in suspence, as we don't know the actual error.

Comment: This link should help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you could check the logs

Comment: Where I can find logs?

Comment: Where are you deploy your spring boot app? on which service?